# How can I open (pop up) an excel file for user using openpyxl in python?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using the openpyxl library to write data into an excel file, I want this file to be automatically opened (to pop up) for user when its finished writing data, I've looked so much but found nothing more than saving the file, which I have already done.

Comment: why not using `subprocess` library, and use `call(["Excel_Software", "arguments"])` , this way you can call external program

Comment: you can get help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74419712/creating-a-temporary-excel-file-using-openpyxl-python/74427140#74427140)

Answer (score 1):

I think one possibility to do this would be with [os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile):

```
import os
os.startfile('your_excel_file.xlsx')
```