# Creating a temporary excel file using openpyxl python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, temporary-files

**I made a program that extracts specific data from an existing excel file.**

Now I want that data to be shown in an excel file but I don't want to save it on the system

[image: Image of that GUI]

This is the GUI of that application which I am making

Now I want to remove that **Select file save destination**
Instead of that I want that when the user clicks on the **Extract button**
It opens up an excel window **without saving a file** and the user can see the extracted data if the user wants they can save it otherwise just close the Excel window without saving it.

Currently, I am using the Openpyxl module to extract the data from an excel file

What should I do?

Currently, I am allowing the user to select a folder to save the file

But I want like when we normally open Excel there is a blank sheet we fill data there and then if we want to save it we save otherwise we just close the window.

I want the same thing here Instead of saving the file I want to open an excel window with that data and if the user wants to save the file they can save or do whatever they want.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be solved using `xlwings` module of python

you can try below code to open excel:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book()  # this will open a new workbook
```

you can find more about xlwings from [documentation](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/)